# View file names in hex?

Tags: debian, filenames, ext4, character-encoding

I have some files with special characters like accented letters.

They are valid names, but for some reason when they are copied across the network to a drive, maybe in another format, the name still looks the same but it is not the same.

I can copy the file back and now I have two files that appear to have the exact same name in the exact same path.

My guess is there are two different values represented the accented letter so they appear the same. Is there any way to view the hex of the name itself, not the file?

This is important because one of my synching apps is getting confused and creating duplicates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pipe the file names to `od` or a similar tool:

```
printf '%s\n' * | od -t x1 -a
```

```
$ ls
Accentué  bar  foo
$ printf '%s\n' * | od -t x1 -a
0000000  41  63  63  65  6e  74  75  c3  a9  0a  62  61  72  0a  66  6f
          A   c   c   e   n   t   u   C   )  nl   b   a   r  nl   f   o
0000020  6f  0a
          o  nl
0000022
```

Many characters can have different representations, even in the same encoding; for example, in UTF-8, 0xC3 0xA9 represents é, and 0x65 0xCC 0x81 represents e followed by “combining acute accent”, which is also displayed as é. Such strings need to be [normalised](https://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) if they are to be compared, but even normalisation has different variants, and different operating systems can store the same string in different ways.

Comment: hilarious how it shows `c3` as `C` and `a9` as `)`, ignoring the high bit. Ok, apparently it's actually documented to do just that...

Comment: Might want to mention Unicode normalization forms, probably what OP is experiencing.

Comment: @ilkkachu+ could instead use `-c` which displays high-bit chars as octal; then you don't really need the `-tx1` if you have practice regrouping bits in your head

Comment: perfect that worked! i ran this directly on each of the drives and see that the same file which has an o with a ^ on top is `c3 b4` on one system and `6f cc 82` on the other. so it's like the encoding was translated somewhere. but i think this gives me what i need to proceed. thanks!

Comment: I just read what you said about different representations in the same encoding. that's interesting but i'm still not sure how it changed. maybe it happened over rsync or something.